# How can I use webpack-dev-server and sass-loader to compile Sass when I make changes to JSON files?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` and a custom Sass importer to allow the importing of JSON files into my Sass. The problem is that when I make changes to the JSON files that are imported into my Sass, the Sass does not re-compile. When making changes to other Sass files that are imported, the Sass re-compiles as expected.

I figure this is down to `json` files not being part of the loader `test`:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        {loader: 'style-loader'}, 
        {loader: 'css-loader'},
        {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            plugins: () => [Autoprefixer]
        }}, 
        {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            data: transformJSONtoSass(app.options),
            importer: SassJSONImporter,
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }}
    ]
},
```

...but if I change the `test` value to `/\.(scss|json)$/` then the loader tries to parse the JSON as Sass and will throw an error. So essentially, I need webpack to trigger a compile of my Sass whenever I make changes to some specified JSON files. I'm hoping I can do this without a custom loader.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the whole app recompiles despite which file type changed, you can try [json-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/#configuration-recommended).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference.